# Python files removed from Jetson

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dependencies, python3, delete

I'm new in Linux, so I tried to remove the `python3.6` package in order to install `python3.8`. However, doing this removed important files. Now when I try to install something or remove, upgrade etc., I get a list of not fully installed or removed depedencies. The list right now if I do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` is the following:

```
python3
update-notifier-common
python3-cffi-backend
printer-driver-m2300w
python3-olefile
libglib2.0-dev-bin
rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
python3-brlapi
python3-commandnotfound
printer-driver-postscript-hp
system-config-printer-common
system-config-printer-udev
python3-pyqt5
python3-requests-unixsocket
language-selector-common
printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
python3-simplejson
python3-click
python3-idna
python3-six
python3-colorama
python3-pyparsing
openprinting-ppds
python3-pymacaroons
python3-certifi
apparmor
gnome-shell
apport-gtk
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
youtube-dl
apturl
python3-wheel
python3-zope.interface
python3-gi-cairo
netplan.io
command-not-found
hplip-data
python3-pkg-resources
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
python3-gi
lsb-release
python3-apport
pyqt5-dev-tools
gnome-control-center
python3-netifaces
orca
gnome-terminal
ubuntu-session
python3-defer
xserver-xorg
python3-problem-report
```

I tried installing `python` again, `remove`, `purge`, `update`, I tried everything that I saw in Google or ChatGPT, but nothing worked. My last option right now is to install Ubuntu again, but since this is an embedded system that works with an SD card, I don't know if I can install it with a USB (I can't access the SD card) or I can use the SD card with the old Ubuntu to reinstall or something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu (esp. desktop systems) are very reliant on the default python3 they come with; the moment it's removed; many provided packages will not work (*or work incorrectly if provided an incorrect version*). You can have more than one python3 version installed; but the default should **not** be changed if you want Ubuntu tools to work.  I'd suggest re-installing  (you didn't say which Ubuntu product; but do note Nvidia/Jetson's repackaged Ubuntu *respins* are not Ubuntu & only Ubuntu based; thus off-topic here).  Also don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is in its last weeks of *standard* support.

Comment: If you delete or alter the default version of Python you kill the OS. Ubuntu needs to have as the default the version of Python it ships with it.  Time to reinstall. Keep in mind 18.04 goes EOL on the 30 th of this month.

Comment: Thanks for the help, theres a way to install or reinstall or factory reset without touching the sd card? With a live usb or something? And yes, is the 18.04

Comment: You've not said which Ubuntu 18.04 LTS product you're using, you can re-install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop rather easily without touching any user config or file, however its more complicated for example with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server...  You've not said what Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISO your system was installed with.  If you want a *factory reset*; restore from your backups - that's what you create them for.  *Note:  if you've removed the default python3; you've also prevented yourself from using tools that require python3 as well; which is a lot of user-geared front-end tools; it's more manual now*

Comment: I don't really know the product, comes pre-flashed with an L4T (Linux for Tegra) environment. I looked for old backups but nothing.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You're using a 3rd party respin OS (based on Ubuntu, but not Ubuntu), and not an official Ubuntu product.. Your system contains both Debian, some 3rd party & a lot of Ubuntu packages*  FYI:  Ubuntu comes from ubuntu.com, where as your product came from https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra-r321 etc

Comment: @David   don't worry about it... I have ~slow internet & am very aware that many comments/answers are typed at the same time, and on occasion comments don't appear on the screen until AFTER a new comment has been updated (*causing the browser to update page & entries appear on my page*)...   Also FYI:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has been given an extra month of *standard support*; it's now EOL end of May 2023 (eg. https://ubuntu.com/blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support and elsewhere...

Comment: @David...   I'm with Ubuntu News so read all notices.. when I saw the date (*May not April*) I sent a request for details to confirm the date, the reply was only recently received which confirmed date was end-May now, with reason for extra month ...  I've not seen any official 'extension' reason given (*that I'm willing to pass on sorry*), but the date 31-May-2023 I've seen on at least two Ubuntu blog articles like that (*a third too, alas that was deleted as some are on occasion*).  I hope to find something, if I do it'll go to fridge/planet/etc.